# after fresh install of mountain lion MAMP goes crazy, php segmentation faults and parse errors

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I was working on developing a wordpress theme/plugin, and stupidly I decided to upgrade to Mountain Lion. I installed it as a fresh copy.

But now, I'm experiencing weird errors.

First error I noticed is part of my plugin doesn't work anymore, it throws error:

```
PHP Parse error:  parse error in /Library/WebServer/Documents/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/sendpress/inc/forms/email-style.2.0.php on line 309, referer: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/
```

line 309: (btw after removing this code and running website everything works)

```
                        <?if ( false !== $this->get_option('canspam') ){
                            echo wpautop( $this->get_option('canspam') );

                        } else { ?> 
                        Blog/Company Name<br>
                                Street Address<br>
                                Anywhere, USA 01234<br>
<?php } ?>
                            </div><br>
```

Previously it there had been no error.

And most importantly I get php segmentation fault error when I put this in functions.php

```
// This function adds javascripts in a proper manner
function holidayge_theme_js() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'tabs', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/tabs.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'lionbars', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.lionbars.0.3.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'slides', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/slides.jquery.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'dropp', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.dropp.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'selectconvert', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/selectConvert.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'easypaginate', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/easypaginate.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'adgallery', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.ad-gallery.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'simplemodal', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.simplemodal.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'settings', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/settings.js' );
}
add_action('init', 'holidayge_theme_js');
```

Apache error:

```
[Fri Jul 27 10:00:35 2012] [notice] child pid 662 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Fri Jul 27 10:00:42 2012] [notice] child pid 653 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

p.s. yes I need to be spanked for upgrading to version 1.0 OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem causing the segmentation fault error is, but perhaps short PHP tag-codes aren't enabled, causing the syntax error?

```
<?php if ( false !== $this->get_option('canspam') ){
    echo wpautop( $this->get_option('canspam') );
} else { ?>
```

Comment: And you are right!

Comment: Was it the short tags or that there was no space between the opening <? and if ?  Short tags are working fine for me in MAMP and OSX 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a mistake in copying the code, but your if statement is not closed:

```
// This function adds javascripts in a proper manner
    function holidayge_theme_js() {
        if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'tabs', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/tabs.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'lionbars', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.lionbars.0.3.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'slides', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/slides.jquery.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'dropp', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.dropp.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'selectconvert', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/selectConvert.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'easypaginate', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/easypaginate.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'adgallery', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.ad-gallery.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'simplemodal', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.simplemodal.js' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'settings', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/settings.js' );
        }
    }
    add_action('init', 'holidayge_theme_js');
```